# Imitate KroneckerProduct

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, performance-tuning

First I will start with the code involving `KroneckerProduct` that I want to replicate. So we have

```
Nx = 2;
Nz = 1;
zas = {3, 2}; (*Nz+1 length vector*)
zzas = Flatten@ConstantArray[zas, Nx+1]
```

giving

```
{3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2}
```

and

```
mat = {{q, w, e},{r, t, y},{u, i, o}};
```

(An `Nx+1` by `Nx+1` matrix)

Then

```
(zzas*KroneckerProduct[mat,IdentityMatrix[Nz+1]]) // MatrixForm
```

produces

```
{{3 q, 0, 3 w, 0, 3 e, 0}, {0, 2 q, 0, 2 w, 0, 2 e}, {3 r, 0, 3 t, 0, 
  3 y, 0}, {0, 2 r, 0, 2 t, 0, 2 y}, {3 u, 0, 3 i, 0, 3 o, 0}, {0, 
  2 u, 0, 2 i, 0, 2 o}}
```

or as an image

[image]

Now, I want to be able to replicate this result using only `zas` and `mat`. The result of the `KroneckerProduct` operation basically multiplies the matrix `mat` by each entry in `zas` - which can be replicated with

```
ceco=Table[zas[[ii]]*mat, {ii, 1, Nz+1}];
```

and then arranges them in a certain way. So, if

```
am=ceco[[1]]
bm=ceco[[2]]
```

then the matrix that results from the `KroneckerProduct` can be created for example as

```
{Append[Riffle[am[[1]], 0], 0], 
 Reverse[Append[Riffle[Reverse[bm[[1]]], 0], 0]], 
 Append[Riffle[am[[2]], 0], 0], 
 Reverse[Append[Riffle[Reverse[bm[[2]]], 0], 0]], 
 Append[Riffle[am[[3]], 0], 0], 
 Reverse[Append[Riffle[Reverse[bm[[3]]], 0], 0]]}
```

Now, I did that by hand, but I want an automatic way of doing it for any `Nx` and `Nz`. I am also open to any other approaches of achieving the same. I basically want something that will be faster than working with the `KroneckerProduct` version, as for large matrices and vectors it becomes very slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your definitions of zzas, mat, and Nz, this gives the desired form:

```
zzas (Outer[Times, mat, IdentityMatrix[Nz + 1]] // ArrayFlatten)
```

Comment: I accept it as an answer as it does what I am asking for. I was hoping it would lead to a performance gain, but it doesn't seem to

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayFlatten[TensorProduct[mat, zas IdentityMatrix[Nz + 1]]] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  3 q & 0 & 3 w & 0 & 3 e & 0 \\
>  0 & 2 q & 0 & 2 w & 0 & 2 e \\
>  3 r & 0 & 3 t & 0 & 3 y & 0 \\
>  0 & 2 r & 0 & 2 t & 0 & 2 y \\
>  3 u & 0 & 3 i & 0 & 3 o & 0 \\
>  0 & 2 u & 0 & 2 i & 0 & 2 o \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: This seems to be slower in computing than the other solution